# How to access a port on the host machine when running docker container on MacOS with --network=host?

Tags: macos, docker

I have set up a couple of containers that interact with each other. The main application container runs on `--network = host` because it queries several mySQL containers running on different ports exposed on the host network.

I am trying to hit the application on the host but get an error:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 36081: Connection refused

I am working on Docker installed on MacOS.

I have read several questions that indicate that docker on MacOS runs on a VM. But what is the workaround to access the application from the host? Any way to get the IP of the said VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `--network=host` on Mac to connect via host ports but binding to host port using `-p` options works.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#/there-is-no-docker0-bridge-on-osx

> I WANT TO CONNECT TO A CONTAINER FROM THE MAC
>
> Port forwarding works
> for localhost; --publish, -p, or -P all work. Ports exposed from Linux
> are forwarded to the host.
>
> Our current recommendation is to publish a port, or to connect from
> another container. This is what you need to do even on Linux if the
> container is on an overlay network, not a bridge network, as these are
> not routed.

For your use case,

You need to create a docker network and attach both the DB and application containers to this network. Then the containers will be able to talk to each other by their name. You can also publish the application container port so that you can access it from your host.

https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

Instead of creating the network, attaching the containers to the network etc manually, you can use docker-compose.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: That is true, however I am using multiple mySQL containers mapped to different ports like so 
`` mySQL1 -p 1200:3306
`` mySQL2 -p 1201:3306
and in my application code, I connect to them using 0.0.0.0:1200 and 0.0.0.0:1201 which is why I need the network=host. The connection between the containers is successful and I am able to hit the application port within the application container but not outside.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Are you not able to connect to application from your Mac or not able to connect to MySQL from your application?

Comment: `--net host` disables all `-p` options (MacOS or otherwise).  0.0.0.0 is a special IPv4 address meaning "everywhere" and you shouldn't usually make outbound connections to it; do you mean 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @ShashankV I am unable to connect to the application from the Mac. Everything else works good.

Comment: @VishakhaLall, You need run your application container using `-p` option. When using `-p` option, you MUST NOT use `--network=host` as @David has suggested. You should be able to connect your application from your Mac at `localhost:port`

Comment: @ShashankV while that is true, my application connects to the mySQL databases exposed on ports 1200 and 1201 (the mySQL containers are available on 0.0.0.0:1200, 0.0.0.0:1201 after being exposed from 3306 internal ports). If I use the -p option, I am unable to connect to the databases since the application is not on the host network. Any suggestions there?

Comment: Ah I get it. You need to create a a bridge network and attach both the DB and application container to the network. Then your containers will be access the other by name. For application container which you need to access from host, you can bind the host port and container port. Instead of doing all this manually, the best way is to use docker-compose which will manage the network creation etc for you.  I've updated the answer with details. 

https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/
https://docs.docker.com/compose/